# Trying to get categories to show

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my categories from mysql database to show and I am adding it to my index page through a php include, here is the category page though this is where I am getting error not sure why though?

```
<?php //which category are we showing?
$category_id = $_GET['catid']; ?>

<h2>All Categories</h2>

<?php
//get 2 latest published posts
$query_latest = "SELECT title, body, date, category_id, post_id
                    FROM posts 
                    WHERE is_published = 1
                    AND category_id = $category_id
                    ORDER BY date DESC";

//run the query code on the DB
$result_latest = mysql_query( $query_latest );


//loop it, work with one post at a time
while( $row_latest = mysql_fetch_array( $result_latest ) ){  ERROR ROW 19
 ?>
<div class="post">
    <h2><?php echo $row_latest['title'] ?></h2>
    <h3>Posted on <?php echo $row_latest['date']; ?> in the category of something</h3>
    <p><?php echo $row_latest['body'] ?></p>
</div>
<?php } //end while loop ?>
```

---

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\schellshockdesign.com\term5final\finalproject\category.php 
on line 19
```

Comment: Lovely SQL injection hole. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. Better read about how to fix this: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: And additionally, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of using `mysql_fetch_array()` in this case.

Comment: Yucky,  $category_id = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["catid"]);
 $category_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $category_id);

Answer (score 1):

You are not connected to a database.

Also, you should be using mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array().

Also, you should be using mysql_real_escape_string on variables you use in your queries.

Comment: If database connection fails, an appropriate warning (or an error) must occur. How can you say that it's not connected?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
<h2>All Categories</h2>

<?php

$category_id = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["catid"]);
$category_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $category_id);

//get 2 latest published posts

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE is_published = '1' AND category_id = '$category_id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
$category_id = $row["category_id"]; 
$post_id = $row["post_id"]; 
$title = $row["title"];
$body = $row["body"];   
$date = $row["date"];   

    echo '<div class="post">
    <h2>'.$title.'</h2>
    <h3>Posted on '.$date.' in the category of something</h3>
    <p>'.$body.'</p>
    </div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps. May be you can debug it using following.

1. Echo the Query and try executing at phpadmin. If it is running there, the problem is with database connection.
2. If query do not run then it clearly shows that the problem is with query ..like fields are not proper,wrong table name, wrong data inputs many others.

Thanks